# Upper case spell check WPF Not working

Tags: wpf, spell-checking

I'm trying to do spell checking in a WPF RichTextBox and working on .net framework 4. In MSDN's documentation on spell check says it does case insensitive spell checking for TextBox and RichTextBox controls.

Unfortunately, the following code doesn't work for words with all uppercase:

```
<RichTextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" xml:lang="en-US"></RichTextBox>
```

Please help me....
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you running windows 10?  I found another unresolved post where OP does not have this issue in windows 7, but does in windows 10 and is still unresolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465106/spellcheck-upper-case-words-using-wpf-in-windows-10

Comment: Ya, I am also running program in windows 10

Answer (score 1):

My google-fu results are looking as though native windows spell checking does not handle English capital letters. Doubly so on Windows 10 where Microsoft Word 20XX and Microsoft Word 365 users are reporting that spell checker will not check uppercase words even when explicitly told to not "Ignore words in UPPERCASE"

Here is a reference to a workaround found on SO (Specifically for XAML `SpellCheck.IsEnabled`)

[C# Texbox Spell Checker Check All Caps Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308655/c-sharp-texbox-spell-checker-check-all-caps-words)

Also, there is the option of using a 3rd party spell checker.

Comment: Actually i am doing in vb.net. Can you tell me how to do this in vb.net

Comment: No, I'm not fluent enough in VB to port things like that.